# Invoke method after viewmodel change

Tags: java, mvvm, zk

I want to invoke a methode (always the same one) after every change in the viewmodel. How can i do that the smart way?

Explanation:
Every changable value in the UI represents options for a container. If an option is changed I want to rerender the container.

The viewmodel consists of several **listboxes with drag & drop** and some **checkboxes**. I don't want to call the method after every **onClick/Select** or drag & drop change.

The container that should be updated is a div-block in a zk window
something like this:

```
<zk>
<window>
<vlayout>
<div id="display"></div>
</vlayout>
</window>
<zk>
```

I want to edit axis from a chart therefore i use java to generate a json string that creates a chart:

```
@Command    
public void script()
    {
            String json = gson.toJson(somechart);

            Clients.evalJavaScript("chart("+ json +")");
    }
```

which starts a javascript function from earlier zul page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function testChart(json){
            var display = jq("$display");

            $(function () { 
                $(display).highcharts(json);
            });
        };
        </script>
```

If the axis from the selection change I want to invoke the script method.

There is a list:

```
List<Axis> selectedAxis
//getters & setters
```

which contains all currently selected axis they are drag&drop -able with another List that contains all not selected axis. There are also other things that can change like title, diagram type etc. and for every single one I want to call the script method after change.

Therefore **@NotifyChange** can not work coz it only operates with framework to rerender the displayed stuff to match the current state of a variable.

**@DepensOn** does change a variable if other variables are changed and rerenders.

**Both do not work for my purpose**, coz i want to call the method **script()** after every change that recreates the chart with new values and does the rendering itself via JS.

For the Drag&Drop i use methods in Java (Insert onInsert [to change order of the list] and DropOn [to drop an item from one list to another])

```
@Command
@NotifyChange({"selectedAxis","notSelectedAxis"})
public void onInserTo(@BindingParam("base") Axis base,@BindingParam("item") Axis item)
{
   ...
}
```

My only conclusion is that i have to call script() in every onChange() method of the Viewmodel.

Comment: Can you provide any code examples? When *exactly* do you want to call the method? When a property changes?

Answer (score 0):

i think the most elegant way considering that you is using the viewmodel way, is using the @NotifyChange annotation. Every changable value in the UI must be associeted with the properties in the viewmodel and the bind correctly associated

there is a sample:

```
Order selected;
Order selected2;
//getter and setter

@NotifyChange("selected")
@Command
public void saveOrder(){
    getService().save(selected);
}
```

i hope help.

Comment: Sry, but that can not work like I updated in my question above.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `@DependsOn` annotation like in the example below. Put the annotation above your container and inside every bean you want to depend on:

[DependsOn Example](http://books.zkoss.org/zk-mvvm-book/8.0/syntax/dependson.html)

Comment: I did try that but nothing happens if values of the list change and after reading the article I think **DependsOn** does not work like i would want to use it. See my updated question maye its clearer now.